# Pressure to stress

Tags: solid-mechanics

If you are considering a material that is just sitting on a table, is this material subjected to stress due to the standard pressure (1ATM) of the air around it?

Answer (score -1):

According to the definition of Stress, its force per unit area.
stress = stress measured in Nm-2 or pascals (Pa)
F = force in newtons (N)
A = cross-sectional area in m2
When its perpendicular to the area, its maximum. 
And Physics says that it will feel stress.